# Setting property value at kv file doesn't affect the value of same variable at py simple code

Tags: python, properties, kivy, kivy-language

By instantiating a custom GridLayout in the kv file, I set a value for the `mes` property, an integer. The value is not passed to the python class variable. I have declared the same property as NumericProperty, but when I run the code, the print statement shows up the default value set at py file rather than the value set at kv file. I can't figure why this happens.

The *main.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class FichaSemApp(App):
    pass

class ShowCal(GridLayout):
    mes = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('VALUE OF mes: ',self.mes)

FichaSemApp().run()
```

I'm using the **init** method because I need some computation for populating the grid.

The *fichasem.kv*

```
ShowCal:
    mes: 2
    cols: 7
    rows: 7
```

Comment: why arent you setting mes in your init method? `self.mes =2` Can you print self.cols or self.rows?

Comment: I would like to use kv lang at most situations. Using the __init__ method is an ugly workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do the following:

## Program

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class ShowCal(GridLayout):
    mes = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('VALUE OF mes: ', self.mes)


class FichaSemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ShowCal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FichaSemApp().run()
```

## Kivy File

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ShowCal>:
    mes: 2
    cols: 7
    rows: 7
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. My ShowCal widget must be the root? Whats missing in my code?

Comment: In this example, your ShowCal widget instance is the root of your widget tree. The missing stuffs are (1) Kivy version either in main.py or fichasem.kv (2) No implementation of build() method to return a Widget instance (the root of your widget tree) (3) kv file - a class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between "<" ">" and followed by ":", defiines how any instance of that class will be graphically represented e.g. <ShowCal>: